# How to define the median for bivariate function?

Tags: probability

I know if we define a function f(x) and its cdf is F(x). The inverse function of cdf is inverseF.

I can define its median as follows: median = inverseF(0.5).

But if I want to get the median for a bivariate function f(x,y). How to define it? Thanks very much!

Comment: You mean a distribution function $f(x)$ - right? Similar to Bob Jansen answer, the search for the notion of a quantile in higher dimensions is much more complicated than in dimension 1.

Answer (score 1):

The standard median is not defined in multiple dimensions but a generalized notion exists as explained in this [CrossValidated answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43009/what-are-the-multidimensional-versions-of-median).